# pointing domain to wildcard sub sub domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wildcard-subdomain, multisite

I have a multisite wordpress install at `plataforma.vendamais.pt`
And I have a wildcard for `*.plataforma`
So all new sites created have this url:

```
client01.plataforma.vendamais.pt
client02.plataforma.vendamais.pt
```

and so on.

I need to connect my client's domains to the correspondent website, so the url `client01.plataforma.vendamais.pt` wont be visible.

As a real case, I have a client's website here:

```
www.tancredoferrari.plataforma.vendamais.pt/
```

I need to have his domain **tancredoferrari.pt** pointing to that address, so his clients will navigate using `tancredoferrati.pt` and wont see any of the `www.tancredoferrari.plataforma.vendamais.pt` url.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 options here:

#### Option 1

An CNAME record on the live domain's DNS should be sufficient to do this - so long as you're happy that the resource requests (images, scripts, styles and so forth) behind the scenes are going to the staging domain URLS (`client02.plataforma.vendamais.pt` and so forth).

#### Option 2

Check out the wordpress plugin [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/). With that you can map the site to multiple domains (and set the primary), which is a better approach.